# Facebook Ads Graph API since&until not working

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get data between a time lapse? I've tried using the "`since` & `until`" parameters, but I still get only the data from the last 30 days.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
> object Ads = client.Get("v2.7/me?fields=adaccounts{campaigns{name,id,status,insights{impressions,date_start,date_stop,clicks,reach,spend}}}&since=2016-12-01&until=2016-12-31");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [Unix timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) or [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) value instead of a UTC date.

As noted in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api):

> `until`: A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the range of time-based data.
>
> `since`: A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of time-based data.

Instead of `2016-12-01`, your dates should look something like `1480550400`.

Comment: I've already replaced the dates ( &since=1480550400&until=1483056000 ) but all the data I retrieve is still from the last 30 days.

Comment: @DanielOsuna I'll keep thinking and get back to you if I find anything